# Cant move gui after removing her 'caption'

Tags: autohotkey

Maybe someone knows if it is possible to move GUI while `-caption` is enabled?

Since the toolbar is removed with GUI -caption, now I can not move GUI with the mouse.

Answer (score 2):

All that is necessary to add to your scripts is the `OnMessage` line and the `WM_LBUTTON` function in the script below to allow you to move the GUI:

```
OnMessage(0x0201, "WM_LBUTTONDOWN")
Gui, -Caption
Gui, Show, w500 h200
return

WM_LBUTTONDOWN() {
    PostMessage, 0xA1, 2,,, A
}

Esc::ExitApp
```